# Show $\int v^2 \left( v_i v_j - \frac13 v^2 \delta_{ij} \right) f_m d^3v = 0 ,$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, kronecker-symbol

I need to show, that
$$\int v^2 \left( v_i v_j - v^2 \delta_{ij} \right) f_m d^3v = 0 ,$$
where 
$$f_m \propto \exp(-v^2), $$
is Maxwellian distributin.
Actually, those indicies frustrates me, I know what is Kronecker delta. Should I take just two integrals:
$$\int v^2 \left( v_x^2 - v^2 \right) f_m d^3v = 0 ,$$
$$\int v^2 v_x v_z f_m d^3v = 0 ,$$
and try to prove them?

So, I post it with error, sorry. First integral should be
$$\int v^2 \left( v_i v_j - \frac13 v^2 \delta_{ij} \right) f_m d^3v = 0 ,$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recall that [in this notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation) repeated indexes imply a sum, so your second expression – assuming you are integrating over $\mathbb R^3$– can be evaluated as follows:
$$\int v^2 v_i v_j f_m d^3v = \int_{v_i>0} v^2 v_i v_j f_m d^3v + \int_{v_i<0} v^2 v_i v_j f_m d^3v$$
$$=\int_{v_i>0} v^2 v_i v_j f_m d^3v - \int_{v_i>0} v^2 v_i v_j f_m d^3v =0.$$

Edit (after OP's correction):

On the other hand, the first integrals add up to
$$ \int v^2 \left( \sum_i v_i^2 - v^2/3 \right) f_m d^3v = \int v^2 \left( v^2 - v^2 \right) f_m d^3v = 0.$$

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, it should be $\frac13$ before Cronecker delta. So, then would be zero from your solution. Thanks!

Comment: Just, how did you get 3 before $v^2$? 
Ohh now I get it, all in the sum.

Comment: One for $i=j=1$, another one for $i=j=2$...

Comment: (The downvoter could at least have said something)